# Creating a Generic Method for Accepting Type Object and return a new Object of Type

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I want to create a generic method for my Service Request and Response with RestSharp.
I want to pass resource url and Object Name of any class and hope to get the response of the same object type which I passed.

I am not finding a way to run this code and I know its not the perfect way, but I will be glad if anyone direct me to correct path
e.g.

```
class Employee
{
    Employee em = new Employee();
    RequestClass CreateRequest = new Request();
    public Employee GetAllEmployee()
    {
        return RequestClass.MyRequest("http://get-all-employee",em);
    }
}

class RequestClass
{
    public Type MyRequest(string resource, Type objectName)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("http://Service-url.com");
        var request = new RestRequest(resource, Method.GET);
        var response = client.Execute(request);
        var result = response.Content;

        Type ClassName = objectName.GetType();
        Object myobject = Activator.CreateInstance(ClassName);

        JsonDeserializer jsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer();
        myobject = jsonDeserializer.Deserialize<Type ClassName>(response);

        return (Type)myobject;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [generic type parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk36dx2.aspx) with a [`new()` constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx):

```
public T MyRequest<T>(string resource) where T : new()
{
    var client = new RestClient("http://Service-url.com");
    var request = new RestRequest(resource, Method.GET);
    var response = client.Execute(request);

    JsonDeserializer jsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer();
    return jsonDeserializer.Deserialize<T>(response);
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
public Employee GetAllEmployee()
{
    var requestClass = new RequestClass();
    return requestClass.MyRequest<Employee>("http://get-all-employee");
}
```